# How do i get only the last result in a column with duplicate values in a query with select?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a question. In the example below, how could i use `select` to return to me only the last values in a table with duplicates? For example, i want to do a select that, in the following example:

```
NOME    |  IDADE
Eduardo | 20
Eduardo | 21
Eduardo | 19
Ozzy    | 30
Ozzy    | 31
Ozzy    | 21
```

It will return to me "Eduardo | 19" and "Ozzy | 21"

Comment: You could easily do it if you have a `TIMESTAMP` or `AutoID` column. Do you have that in your table?

Comment: Without some way of identifying which row is 'last', the problem is essentially insoluble. I suggest you either revise or delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as a last row.  If you want the smallest `idade`, then use `min()`:

```
select nome, min(idade)
from t
group by nome;
```

If you do have a column that specifies the ordering and you want the row with the largest such value, then:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.? = (select max(t2.?) from t t2 where t2.nome = t.nome);
```

`?` is the column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: Actually i wanted the last entry... i tried to make this query searching by the duplicate name with the highest ID, but i couldn't do it... is there a way to do this that way?